# Codeforces exercise 71

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a problem with this exercise:
https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/71/A
My SC is:

```
a=input()
b=a.isdigit()
if b==False:
    if len(a)<10:
        print(a)
    else:
        b=a[0]
        c=str(len(a)-2)
        d=a[-1]
        print(b+c+d )
```

and it works, my output is correct but i see a a wrong verdict: wrong output format Unexpected end of file - token expected
what should i improve? what is wrong?

Comment: Where do you see this error?

Comment: Your logic does not match the question you linked to. Is this your entire code, or did you leave something out? Hint: this question requires a loop!

Comment: i see this error when i send out my python file to this website to check my answear

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a loop to loop over all test cases.

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    word = input()
    if len(word)<11:
        print(word)
    else:
        print(word[0]+str(len(word)-2))+word[-1])
```